# Unable to resolve service for type System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-5, iasyncenumerable

I'm having this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[MyProject.Interfaces.IFooReader]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'MyProject.Services.FooService'.'

while trying to resolve `IFooService` with `var fooService = provider.GetRequiredService<IFooService>();`.

Here is the `FooService` class:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<IFooReader> _foosReaders;

    public PriceService(IAsyncEnumerable<IFooReader> foosReaders)
    {
        this._foosReaders = foosReaders;            
    }
}
```

Here is the DI container:

```
services.AddScoped<IFooReader, FooServiceA>(); 
services.AddScoped<IFooReader, FooServiceB>(); 
services.AddScoped<IFooReader, FooServiceC>(); 

services.AddScoped<IFooService, FooService>(); //assuming stateless
```

It looks like the native .net-core DI container does not support injection of `IAsyncEnumerable`, any way to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you need this as an IAsyncEnumerable? I think the IEnumerable may work fine in this case.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` is not supported. Injecting an `IAsyncEnumerable` makes little sense, as all your `IFooReader` implementations, as they are currently registered, are all constructed synchronously. And DI components shouldn't be loaded asynchronously, because [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and you should be able to [compose your object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of **IEnumerable** instead of **IAsncEnumerable** should resolve this issue.

```
 public class FooService : IFooService

{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFooReader> _foosReaders;

    public PriceService(IEnumerable<IFooReader> foosReaders)
    {
        this._foosReaders = foosReaders;            
    }
}
```